# How to return custom Errorlevel in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exit-code, errorlevel

I want to run the script from command line, and get the error level.
I use this batch script.

```
set log=C:\Users\PowerShell\XML\Log.txt
set PS=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
set PS=%PS%\powershell.exe 

"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" C:\Users\XML.ps1 -i C:\Users\A2.txt -j C:\Users\Fb.xml
   
echo %ERRORLEVEL% > "%log%"
```

I tried this script to get the custom errorlevel, If it is found, it will return `123`, otherwise `456`. But It always gives me `1`.

```
$regex = [regex]$Pattern

$matching = $regex.Match($FBString)
if ($matching.Success) {
    while ($matching.Success) {
        "Match found: {0}" -f $matching.Value
        Exit 123
        $matching = $matching.NextMatch()
    }
}
else {
    "Not Found"
    Exit 456
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Exit` to `Return` . **Exit** will exit your script. **Return** will return values that you wish for.

Comment: It works when I run it from powershell. But I want to get the errorlevel value by using batch file

Comment: 0 indicates that script ran successfully and 1 indicates that there is an error. If you want to capture the same in batch then you have redirect them to stdout

Comment: ( exit <n> ) set the system %errorlevel% environment variable... while ( return <n> ) will try to pass the object <n> to the calling code... or by default write it to out-default... so is you want to use batch files or other executables to call your powershell code and interact with the result in the OS standard way... you should use exit <n> ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to disagree, as your answer is not true (at least not any longer). [Using `exit \b 123` is best practice for exit-codes since windows 2000/xp](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) (pretty much at the button of this link).

Answer (score 2):

You can write the logic in your script
so any exit point will set the `%errorlevel%` system variable...

and create your "error return logic"...

something lihe this:

```
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ) { exit 0  }
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 1 ) { exit 1  }
if ( $x -gt 1 ) { exit 2  }
if ( $x -lt 1 ) { exit 3  }
...
```

and then you can inspect from a batch file for `%errorlevel% == 0`, `1`, `2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with powershell -file.  The default is powershell -command.  Once that script is over, with -command the session is still going.

Comment: Thank you very much! This saved my day ... and should be the accepted answer (no rewriting of scripts, the desired exit code directly put into %errorlevel%).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the batch file. It should be like this :

```
set log=C:\Users\PowerShell\XML\Log.txt
set PS=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
set PS=%PS%\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File


"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\XML.ps1 -i C:\Users\A2.txt -j C:\Users\Fb.xml

echo %ERRORLEVEL% > "%log%"
```

For the first PowerShell script is correct already.